# Displaying the correct django authentication framework information in custom admin page

Tags: python, django, authentication, backend, admin

I am trying to display the password in the Admin backend table in the following way, containing the algorithm, iterations, salt and hash:

[image]

However, my current page looks like the following:

[image]

As you can see it is just the hashed password, not displaying any of the information unlike the above. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Please find my code below:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from hobbies.models import extendedUser, User, Hobby
from .forms import LoginForm, SignUpForm
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField

#admin.site.register(User,UserAdmin)



class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = SignUpForm
    form = LoginForm
    model = extendedUser
    readonly_fields = ["password"]
    list_display = ('email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)


    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password', 'city')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_staff', 'is_active')}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password', 'is_staff', 'is_active')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)

admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Thank you for your time,
Alex

Comment: Why don't you take a look in the source code how they display it? Just a thought

Comment: @Swift do you mean view the code from the console of the web browser?

Answer (score 1):

I think they use display using this function:

`get_session_auth_hash()` which is a part of the base abstract user in `django.contrib.auth.base_user`